# How to safely remove drush via pear and then install via composer?

Tags: drush, composer

I have drush 5 installed on my VPS running CentOS 6. Drush was installed using PEAR.
Can I just remove the drush directory and the simlinks and then install drush 7 using composer?

I have been searching for a way to uninstall drush, but all I get are tutorials to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drush doesn't really have any components that need to be "uninstalled".  If the drush binary is somewhere on your PATH, then it's installed.  If you just go ahead and install Drush 7 via composer, and insure that the newer Drush appears first in your PATH, then you can even leave Drush 5 on your system with no ill effects.  You might even want to make a 'drush5' alias as a fallback, in case -- although personally, I run Drush 6 and Drush 7 on my system.  I use Drush 7 for most things.

Answer (score 5):

**Uninstalling Drush using Pear**

If Drush has been installed using Pear, it can be removed using the following command.

```
pear uninstall drush/drush
```

**Installing Drush via Composer**

For the most current install instructions, refer to the [Drush GitHub page](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush).

1) Add Composer's global bin directory to the system PATH (recommended):

```
sed -i '1i export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' $HOME/.bashrc
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

2) Install Drush

```
composer global require drush/drush
```